# TabActivity, nested Activities in Tabs and onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-activity, camera, tabactivity

I have main TabActivity in my project which contains nested activities in each tab. In nested activity i call standart camera application with startActivityForResult() and try to handle result of call by onActivityResult() method. I was expecting that onActivityResult will be executed after camera application finishing, but it called before. What to do in this situation? How to handle camera results?

Comment: I want to handle Activity.RESULT_CANCELED and Activity.RESULT_OK in activity which embedded in TabActivity